# Hibernate error - collection foreign key mapping has wrong number of columns

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm stuck with this error when trying to persist an Entity class in a Postgres database -

`Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: collection foreign key mapping has wrong number of columns: com.example.model type: component[id,id]`

My **Entity class** looks like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name ="parent_table", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(name = "OneAndTwoAndThreeAndFour", columnNames = { "one", "two",
            "three","four"}) })
public class A implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "one", nullable = false)
    private String one;

    @Column(name = "two", nullable = false)
    private String two;

    @Column(name = "three", nullable = false)
    private Integer three;

    @Column(name = "four", nullable = false)
    private Integer four;

    @Column(name = "five")
    private Long five;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(
            name="join_table",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="parent_table_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @Column(name="some_column", nullable = false)
    private Set<String> set;

    public A() {
        super();
    }
}
```

I had to create the tables in postgres myself as our application is not entirely on Spring boot. The **SQL statements to create the tables** -

```
 create table parent_table (
    id int4 not null,
    one varchar(255) not null,
    two varchar(255) not null,
    three int4 not null,
    four int4 not null,
    five int8,  
    primary key (id)
);

    create table join_table (
        parent_table_id int4 not null, 
        some_column varchar(255) not null, 
        primary key (parent_table_id, some_column)
    );
    
    alter table parent_table add constraint OneAndTwoAndThreeAndFour unique (one, two, three, four);
    
    alter table join_table add constraint PWConstraint foreign key (parent_table_id) references parent_table;
```

I've already spent hours trying to debug this problem using Hibernate logs and other SO posts but no luck so far :( Please help..

Comment: Which versions of Hibernate and Spring Boot do you use?